# Tab navigation: Conventional or optimised for common use case?

Tags: forms, data-entry, addresses

Our **users** work multiple hours a week entering address data in a form. All users are considered advanced users.

There are two most common **use cases**

- a. Always the same and not all address fields are filled in.
- b. An address is inserted by clicking a button

One **idea** for efficient data entry is skipping

- a. infrequently used fields
- b. all fields

when tabbing through the form.

**Pro:** Quick navigation to relevant fields with as little as possible tab navigation .

**Con:** Contradicts first time expectation, resulting in first time confusion and a learning curve. For non-standard form entry mouse input is required.

Would you implement this idea or rather stick with conventional tabbing behaviour? I'm tending towards a no for a. and yes for b. Do you have any experience with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the conventional tabbing behavior. You also have to take in account that tabbing is important from an accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT skip form fields or prevent keyboard nav to interactive elements. Always refer to [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/) for interactive elements.

DO apply smart autofill so people don't have to key in the same info multiple times. That's just good usability for everyone, including keyboard navigators. :)